# Attribute routing and localizing controller/action names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, routes, culture

I would like to localize my URL's bases on language, for example:

- http://example.com/en/recipes/manage
- http://example.com/nl/recepten/beheren

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC 5 attribute routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("{language}/recipes")]
public class RecipesController : BaseController
{
    [Route("manage")]
    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        ...
    }    
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is localizing the full URL a good idea?
2. Any pointers on how to change the controller and action part in a URL based on language?

Thanks!

EDIT: got it working as follows:

```
 [Route("{language:regex(nl)}/recepten/beheren")]
 [Route("{language:regex(en)}/recipes/manage")]  
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
 }
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it works...

Comment: Localized URL is definitely a good idea. For SEO and for usability. Your second approach might just be a bit difficult for lots of pages with lots of translations. You couldn't use a CMS?

Comment: It's a custom made portal, so no.... I like the approach of attribute routing because you define routing where the controller actions are, but maybe there's a way to do these translations centrally. I tried with a custom constraint, but I always get the exception 'the inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint'